# str_replace from a particular position in a string

Tags: php, string

I want to replace a string within a string, but only a specific part of it, e.g. from character position 7 onwards

e.g. 'test.string.1' and I want to replace the second '.' with e.g. '2'

I have this obviously:

```
$string = str_replace('.', '2', $string);
```

But that will replace both periods, I just want replace the second period, and some strings may have multiple periods, I just want to replace the period after an arbitrary character position. The first period after e.g. 5 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use substr and str_replace.

```
$string = 'test.string.1';
$string = substr($string, 0, 7).str_replace('.', '2', substr($string, 7));
echo $string;
```

Result: test.string21

Answer (score 0):

It is probably cleanest to target the desired dot with the simplicity of `strpos()` with the 3rd parameter representing your starting point.  If a dot exists after the starting point, replace and you're done.  This technique works because you are replacing a lone single-byte character with a lone single-byte character -- if that luxury changes, this technique may cease to be appropriate.

The regex technique is just as stable, but the pattern may look a bit unwieldy to the untrained eye.  `^` marks the start of the string; the `.` represents any non-newline character. The rendered `{5}` (quantifier) to follow the dot will match the first 5 characters in the string. `[^.]*` is a negated character class with a zero or more quantifier.  This will match any number of non-dot characters. `\K` means forget any previously matched characters.  Finally, `\.` matches the targeted literal dot to be replaced.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jClan))

```
$str = "test.string.1.sometext.more";
$startingOffset = 5;
$pattern = '~^.{' . $startingOffset . '}[^.]*\K\.~';
$replacement = 2;
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);

echo "\n---\n";

$offset = strpos($str, '.', $startingOffset);
if ($offset !== false) {
    $str[$offset] = $replacement;
}
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
test.string21.sometext.more
---
test.string21.sometext.more
```